# Does creating multiple custom stateless widgets inside another custom widget affect performance?

Tags: flutter, dart

So i have TabBar and i make resuable Tab or custom widget `TabBarPage` inside the `TabBarView`.

my question is does my approach like this code below do affect bad perfomance or is it the same if i not make any custom widget inside custom widget ?

```
TabBarView(
            children: [
              TabBarPage(
                child: NowPlaying(),
              ),
              TabBarPage(
                child: Upcoming(),
              ),
              TabBarPage(
                child: Popular(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

inside TabBarPage i have `final Widget child;` that is filled with NowPlaying, Upcoming, or Popular   and this three child have the same code but different provider

```
Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18.w, 0, 18.w, 0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: this.widget.child,
          ),
        ),
```

and in NowPlaying, Upcoming, or Popular i have my 2 another custom widget (TabLoading, TabContent)

```
class NowPlaying extends StatelessWidget {
  const NowPlaying({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<NowPlayingProvider>(
      builder: (context, data, child) {
        if (data.isLoading == true) return TabLoading();
        return TabContent(data: data.nowPlaying);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Custom widgets do not necessarily equate to bad performance. I'd start with brushing up on performance in flutter with this: https://docs.flutter.dev/perf

Comment: you can answer your own question by opening the performance inspector of your ide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously No, By creating multiple custom stateless widgets inside another custom widget there is no effect on performance, go through [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf)